# Blackberry application terminated

Tags: blackberry

I am getting error

> Application is not responding; process terminated

when I am using a `listfield.Dats` is coming from server. Here is the code:

```
listnew = new ListField() {

        /*
         * protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) { }
         */



        protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {

            listFieldIndex = listnew.getSelectedIndex();
            listnew.setFocus();
            System.out.println(listFieldIndex);
            if (listFieldIndex < 0) {
                listFieldIndex = 0;

            }
            try {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(
                        new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                /*ODProgDetailScreen.shows.removeAllElements();
                                System.out.println("Value is-----"
                                        + listFieldIndex);
                                // System.out.println("ID IS EQUAL TO:-"+
                                // progurl);
                                ODProgDetailScreen.progDetailURL = ((Program) programList2
                                        .elementAt(listFieldIndex)).getId();
                                ODProgDetailScreen.progTitle = ((Program) programList2
                                        .elementAt(listFieldIndex))
                                        .getTitle();
                                // ProgramDetails.shows.removeAllElements();
                                UiApplication.getUiApplication()
                                        .pushScreen(new ODProgDetailScreen());
                                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(
                                        getScreen());*/
                            }
                        });
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return true;
        }

    };

    listnew.setRowHeight(40);

    // setEmptyString("Hooray, no tasks here!", DrawStyle.HCENTER);

    listnew.setCallback(this);

    rows = new Vector();

    for (int x = 0; x < mDCtaegory.size(); x++) {
        Hashtable hs = (Hashtable)mDCtaegory.elementAt(x);
        row = new TableRowManager();

        // SET THE PRIORITY BITMAP FIELD
        // if high priority, display p1 bitmap

        /*artistImgField = new URLBitmapField(Bitmap
                .getBitmapResource("res/images/bg.jpg"));*/
        HTTPManager engine = new HTTPManager();
          BitmapField bitmap= new BitmapField(engine.readImageFromURL((String) hs.get("img"), 40, 40));
          row.add(bitmap);

BitmapField bitmap1=new BitmapField(engine.readImageFromURL((String) hs.get("ratingimage"), 40, 40));
BitmapField bitmap2=new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("arrow.png"));
        //row.add(bitmap1);


        LabelField task = new LabelField(hs.get("title"), LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);



        row.add(task);
        row.add(bitmap1);
        row.add(bitmap2);

        rows.addElement(row);
    }
    listnew.setSize(rows.size());
    gridbackManager=new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL){
          protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics)
          {  

                    int c = graphics.getColor();
                    //graphics.setColor(Color.WHITESMOKE);
                    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, backbitmap.getWidth(), backbitmap.getHeight(),backbitmap,0,0);

                    //graphics.setColor(c);

            super.paintBackground(graphics);
          }
          protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
          {
              int width = backbitmap.getWidth();
              int height = backbitmap.getHeight();
              super.sublayout( width, height);
              layoutChild(_vfm,width, height);
              setPositionChild(_vfm,0, 0);
              setExtent( width, height);
          }
        };
        mainlayout=new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL){
              protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics)
              {  

                        int c = graphics.getColor();
                        //graphics.setColor(Color.WHITESMOKE);
                        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, backbitmap.getWidth(), backbitmap.getHeight(),backbitmap,0,0);

                        //graphics.setColor(c);

                super.paintBackground(graphics);

              }
              protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
              {
                  int width = backbitmap.getWidth();
                  int height = backbitmap.getHeight();
                  super.sublayout( width, height);
                  layoutChild(backbittopfield,maxWidth, maxHeight);
                  setPositionChild(backbittopfield,15, 20);
                  layoutChild(gridbackManager,maxWidth, maxHeight);
                  setPositionChild(gridbackManager,15, 43);
                  layoutChild(backbitbottomfield,maxWidth, maxHeight);
                  setPositionChild(backbitbottomfield,15, 194);
                  setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
              }
            };
    _vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL
            | Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            int[] X_PTS_MAIN = { 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getWidth(),
                    0 };
            int[] Y_PTS_MAIN = { 0, 0, Display.getHeight(),
                    Display.getHeight() };
            int[] drawColors_MAIN = { Color.WHITESMOKE, Color.WHITESMOKE,
                    Color.WHITESMOKE, Color.WHITESMOKE };

            try {
                // Draw the gradients
                g.drawShadedFilledPath(X_PTS_MAIN, Y_PTS_MAIN, null,
                        drawColors_MAIN, null);

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                System.out.println("Bad arguments.");
            }

            g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITESMOKE);
            g.clear();
            // Call super to paint the graphics on the inherited window
            super.paint(g);

        }

        protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status,
                int time) {
            this.invalidate();
            return super.navigationMovement(dx, dy, status, time);
        }

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

            layoutChild(listnew, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setPositionChild(listnew, 0, 0);

            setExtent( 292, 150);
        }

    };
    _vfm.add(listnew);
    mainlayout.setBackground(bg);
    mainlayout.add(backbittopfield);
    gridbackManager.add(_vfm);
    mainlayout.add(gridbackManager);
    mainlayout.add(backbitbottomfield);
    add(headerbitmapfield);
    add(mainlayout);
    // this.add(listnew);
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            listnew.invalidate();
        }
    }, 500, true);
```

Is it due to the `list.invalidate()` that I am using at the bottom?

Comment: I would try setting a breakpoint and debugging until the app code stops executing. Also, I've had this happen when I created an infinite loop, so watch for that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANR is because you are trying to make an HTTP connection on the UI thread. This is a [big no-no](http://docs.blackberry.com/de-de/developers/deliverables/29251/Event_thread_1593335_11.jsp)! You need to initialize the ListField as empty and start a separate, background thread to read the data. When the data has all arrived, call `invokeLater` with a Runnable that will populate the list.

Comment: but i am doing the same thing in my prior list field screen and i can fethc the data easily,no error,same logic i am using dere

Comment: If the request happens quick enough it just looks like a temporary hang in the application. If it takes too long the system will assume the app is frozen and just terminate it.

Comment: @jprofitt Thank you for the helpful information.So how can i overcome it

Comment: This is where i call my HTTPManager Class

Comment: @arunabha - Like I said, you need to start a worker thread that does the loading. That way, the UI thread can proceed without delays. If you were doing this in other screens and it was working, you were just lucky with the timing.

Comment: Thank you everyone,i have got some idea.Just want to ask that,where i should put the invokeLater code,from where i am calling the http manager and fetching the contents or from where i am calling the ui screen to fill the listfield

Comment: After you fetch the contents (while running in the background thread), create a runnable that will fill the listfield. Pass that runnable to invokeLater so it will run on the UI thread. You need to do this because all changes to the display must be done from the UI thread.